# Create new column from matched list of words in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, contains

I have a dataframe with a column that contains a string with mixed delimiters (space vs. none) between words as well as numbers:

```
'Widgets'

MakeOneModelx2000
MakeOneModelx Modely2000
MakeOneModelx Modely Modelz2000
Make123456ThreeModelfoo
Make123456FourModelbar
```

I want to separate the make and model and create new columns within the datafile. The problem is that the model names build on themselves so I can't do a simple df.str.contains().

The answer by https://stackoverflow.com/users/704848/edchum on [How to Add a New Column With Selected Values from Another Column In Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22902885/how-to-add-a-new-column-with-selected-values-from-another-column-in-python) is close, but since the same word is used in different models, it does not give me the models which match all the words.

I know the possible words for make and model, so currently i'm creating masks for each word:

```
Make1_mask = df['Widgets'].str.contains('Make1')
Make2_mask = df['Widgets'].str.contains('Make2')
```

Then assign to the new column 'Make'

```
df.ix[Make1_mask,'Make'] = 'Make1'
df.ix[Make2_mask,'Make'] = 'Make2'
```

Same for Models:

```
# First model contains same words as Model2 and Model3
Model1_mask = df['Model'].str.contains('Modelx Modely Modelz')
Model2_mask = df['Model'].str.contains('Modelx Modely')
Model3_mask = df['Model'].str.contains('Modelx')
# Completely unique models are easier
Modelfoo_mask = df['Model'].str.contains('Modelfoo')
Modelbar_mask = df['Model'].str.contains('Modelbar')
```

Then assign to the new column 'Model'

```
df.ix[Model1_mask ,'Model'] = 'Model1'
df.ix[Model2_mask ,'Model'] = 'Model2'
df.ix[Model3_mask ,'Model'] = 'Model3'
df.ix[Model4_mask ,'Model'] = 'Model Foo'
df.ix[Model5_mask ,'Model'] = 'Model Bar'
```

This works in a way, but depending on how I order assignment of the models, it will overwrite the models that contain the same words.

Is there a way to ensure that the Model is assigned correctly so that the model with only one of the three words is not considered the same in models that contain that word and others?

So I get:

```
Widgets                                    Make         Model

MakeOneModelx2000                          Make1        Model1
MakeOneModelx Modely2000                   Make1        Model2
MakeOneModelx Modely Modelz2000            Make1        Model3
Make123456ThreeModelfoo                    Make3        Model Foo
Make123456FourModelbar                     Make4        Model Bar
```

Obviously new to Python / Pandas so I'm sure there is a more efficient way to do this which would be appreciated as well. I put the numbers in the Widgets column for completeness. I'm using `df.str.extract()` to create new columns based on the model number (123456) and year (2000):

```
df['Year'] = df['Widgets'].str.extract('(201/d)',expand=False)
df['Model Number'] = df['Widgets'].str.extract('(/d/d/d/d/d/d)',expand=False)
```

Thanks for your time!